# Energy spread and reversibility of a thermodynamic process

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, reversibility

Recently, while studying thermodynamics I came across something called a **reversible process**, textbook stated that an infinitesimally slow process can be termed as a reversible process.

This doesn't sound complete, so I did  a bit more research and came to a conclusion that this definition corresponds to energy spread between systems.

Let's consider an situation :

We have a system of two bars (A,B) made of hypothetically ductile and malleable metal, 5 atoms each.
A is hotter than B (let's say the energy doesn't spread out elsewhere than the 2 bars). An electron of an atom of the hotter bar A radiates some energy that is absorbed by an atom in other bar B.

There is an extremely small probability that the atom which absorbed the radiated energy will radiate the same energy back to the atom that radiated it initially.
*(Quite a tongue twister, isn't it)*

Well, this condition is *too ideal* considering that electrons move and forces other species in the bar exert on the the the specie in action. Concluding that no energy that is lost can be gained the exact reverse way.

Is this kind of intuition correct for understanding why reversible processes are not feasible.

If non, please correct.

Comment: The textbook is wrong; infinitesimally slow resistive heating, for example, is still irreversible. But it is true that no real process is reversible. Entropy is generated every time energy moves down a gradient (e.g., in pressure or temperature), but this gradient is necessary to drive the process at a nonzero rate.

Comment: Get a decent textbook like Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and Van New. Such a book will tell you more precisely how to judge reversible and irreversible processes.

Comment: just try search in this website in the top window by entering the words: "quasi-static reversible irreversible" and gets you this link https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=quasi-static+reversible+irreversible+ Enjoy!